# Simplifying a complicated expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does anyone can provide a way to simplify the following expression? For example by introducing a new constant which contains some constants and reduces the expression

[image]

One can use $x=r_e+r_p$ for example, but it does not reduce the expression effectively.

Comment: Well, there's $g_p^+ = A$, where $A = ...$. That is a lot simpler, if not at all helpful! In order for someone to simplify this, they need to know what is important in it and what can be safely hidden away. I.e., they have to understand what use you will make of the result. Unfortunately, the only person who knows that is you. The rest of us cannot help unless you explain it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  You can assume that all of these have the same worth. I just want to obtain a simpler experssion!

Comment: One suggestion would be to define $\beta = \alpha\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{c_{ep}}}, q_e = \frac{\sqrt{c_{ep}}}{\sqrt 2}r_e, q_p = \frac{\sqrt{c_{ep}}}{\sqrt 2}r_p$. I believe that would remove almost every instance of $c_{ep}$ and many of the $2$s in the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acting on my suggestion in the comment (but dispensing with subscripts and greek letters for the sake of convenience), let
$$x = \sqrt{\frac {c_{ep}}2}r_e\quad\longrightarrow\quad r_e = \sqrt{\frac 2{c_{ep}}}x\\y=\sqrt{\frac {c_{ep}}2}r_p\quad\longrightarrow\quad r_p = \sqrt{\frac 2{c_{ep}}}y\\z = \sqrt{\frac 2{c_{ep}}}\alpha\quad\longrightarrow\quad\alpha = \sqrt{\frac {c_{ep}}2}z$$

Then we get
$$\begin{align}g_p^+ &= \frac 1{c_{ep}}e^{-2xy}\bigg(\left(e^{2z(x + y)} - e^{4xy - 2z(x-y)}\right)+z\sqrt\pi e^{z^2 + (x+y)^2}\big[\operatorname{erf}(x + y + z) - \operatorname{erf}(x - y + z)\big]\bigg)\\
&= \frac 1{c_{ep}}\bigg(e^{2xz + 2yz - 2xy} - e^{2xy + 2yz - 2xz}+z\sqrt\pi e^{x^2+y^2+z^2}\big(\operatorname{erf}(x + y + z) - \operatorname{erf}(x - y + z)\big)\bigg)\end{align}$$

Noting
$$(x-y+z)^2 = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (2xz - 2xy - 2yz)\\(x+y-z)^2 = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (2xy - 2xz - 2xz)$$ and the fact that the error function is odd: $$- \operatorname{erf}(x - y + z) = \operatorname{erf}(y - x - z)$$

This can be converted to 
$$g_p^+ = \frac {e^{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{c_{ep}}\bigg(e^{-(x+y-z)^2} - e^{-(x-y+z)^2}+z\sqrt\pi\big(\operatorname{erf}(y + x + z) + \operatorname{erf}(y - x - z)\big)\bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you so much.